# GDAL 2 not working in AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, gdal

I installed GDAL and necessary libraries by following this link: https://github.com/vancityhuddy/aws-eb-gdal-example

Had to use aws s3 instead of s3cmd tho, and removed PYTHONPATH from environment variables since EB's configuration already comes with PYTHONPATH. Anyways, here is a copy of my .config file.

```
container_commands:
  01_install_geos:
    command: |
      sudo wget ***RemovedTheURLForSecurity***/geos-3.6.4.tar.gz
      sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/geos
      sudo tar -xvf geos-3.6.4.tar.gz -C /usr/local/geos
      sudo rm -f geos-3.6.4.tar.gz
    test: "[ ! -d /usr/local/geos ]"
  02_install_proj4:
    command: |
      sudo wget ***RemovedTheURLForSecurity***/proj4-5.2.0.tar.gz
      sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/proj4
      sudo tar -xvf proj4-5.2.0.tar.gz -C /usr/local/proj4
      sudo rm -f proj4-5.2.0.tar.gz
    test: "[ ! -d /usr/local/proj4 ]"
  03_install_gdal:
    command: |
      sudo wget ***RemovedTheURLForSecurity***/gdal-2.4.4.tar.gz
      sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/gdal
      sudo tar -xvf gdal-2.4.4.tar.gz -C /usr/local/gdal
      sudo rm -f gdal-2.4.4.tar.gz
    test: "[ ! -d /usr/local/gdal ]"
  04_migrate:
    command: "source /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate && python3 manage.py makemigrations && python3 manage.py migrate"
    leader_only: true
  05_createsu:
    command: "source /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate && python3 manage.py createsu"
    leader_only: true
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: core.settings
    PATH: /usr/local/gdal/bin:$PATH
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/proj4/lib:/usr/local/geos/lib:/usr/local/gdal/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
    GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/gdal/lib/libgdal.so
```

But still, this error occurs even thought the geos, proj4 and gdal commands completed successfully,

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not find the GDAL library (tried "gdal", "GDAL", "gdal3.1.0", "gdal3.0.0", "gdal2.4.0", "gdal2.3.0", "gdal2.2.0", "gdal2.1.0", "gdal2.0.0"). Is GDAL installed? If it is, try setting GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH in your settings.
```

When I add GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH in settings.py according to the message. This is what it shows:

```
OSError: /usr/local/gdal/lib/libgdal.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm clueless here. I have been trying to deploy this for two days. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you build the GDAL library?

Comment: @stdunbar yes, using an EC2 instance exactly how it was recommended by the github repo

Comment: When I compile GDAL `libgdal.so` is in `.libs`, not `lib`.  This is using https://download.osgeo.org/gdal/2.4.4/gdal-2.4.4.tar.gz.  Where is `libgdal.so` in your build?

Comment: Well, for some reason the script didn't work for me. Followed [this article](https://medium.com/@shudson250/a-how-to-geodjango-deployed-on-aws-368948453f4d) to solve it.
Had to make a few changes to it to work. I'll describe it in an answer clearly.